# silverlight cant get elevated permissions

Tags: silverlight, certificate, pfx, wia

i know theres a lot of info about this, and i spent about 3 days (and nights...) reading and trying everything i saw. but still cant get it to work

i have a silverlight app thats supposed to access WIA for scanning. on localhost it works great but in the auto-generated SilverlightTestPage.htm it does not have elevated permissions. try as i might.

**things/steps ive tried**

- created a test certificate to sign the xap file
- double clicked said pfx file to install in trusted publishers and also Trusted Root Certification Authorities. the install worked, but still no elevated permissions.
- ive set the require elevated permissions also in the signing page and also in the out-of-browser settings
- set AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser regkeys to 1 also in 32 bit and also 64bit
- set UpdateConsentMode to 1

i think this basically sums up all steps necessary. but still its not working even in the tespage on my local machine

please advise, im at my wits end

TIA

Comment: any ideas anybody? this is really important for us. we cant find any additional leads. thanks.

Comment: Already I had done. and your steps are true. i think if you are using Local IIS instead of IIS Express you must be add your certificate to iis and use SSL.